# In interpreting Jinja2 templates, why does code object have a null filename?

Tags: python, jinja2

I'm trying to pick apart Jinja2's `TemplateSyntaxError` to see why it doesn't tell me the exact file name in which a syntax error is found.

I'm actually introducing this error in a sub-template on purpose to try to better understand this templating system. Upon getting the syntax error, I see `File "<unknown>", line 4, in template` in my Flask preview server. The line number is correct, but the debugger appears confused about the file from which the problem originated, which is very annoying. I'm uncertain as of yet what the name of the code object, `template` represents.

As someone has pointed out, the `<unknown>` is used here as a throwaway when the filename value of the code object is null. After reading through a [few](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#index-59) [references](http://late.am/post/2012/03/26/exploring-python-code-objects) for code objects, I've not yet had luck wrapping my head around this weirdness.

Someone appears to get a similar error in [this github issue](https://github.com/Anomareh/mynt/issues/48).

Comment: Could you provide a sample code setup that produces this error?

Comment: No problem, actually I can reproduce it easily using an *erroneous* template string with Flask as such `flask.render_teplate_string('{% test %}')`.

Comment: Yes, that was what I did as well. I am currently tracking down the error, I just needed to know to dig into Jinja deeper, it's definitely something in the `debug.py` file you linked to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May it be that it's just an arbitrary value provided by Jinja2 to some dynamically generated code?

```
>>> code = compile('print("test")', '<unknown>', 'exec')
>>> code
<code object <module> at 0x1064b6e30, file "<unknown>", line 1>
>>> exec code
test
>>> code.co_filename
'<unknown>'
```

And there it seems to be indeed in [jinja2/debug.py - translate_syntax_error](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/jinja2/blob/4c7b51bbd0582df50a2400911071ed5109e0c31d/jinja2/debug.py#L143).

The explanation of why that is is rather straightforward. The whole machinery, starting with [`flask.render_template_string`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.render_template_string) through [`jinja2.Environment.from_string`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#jinja2.Environment.from_string) down to Jinja2 exception handlers does not take any concern about the origin of the template string passed in.

While it would be possible to tunnel some more information top down, what would be the benefit of it anyway? In case of an exception you get a complete stack trace with appropriate local information available on each level of it, including from where you passed in the string and the line number in the template string that erred, e.g.:

```
File "jinja2-uknown-filename.py", line 7, in index
return flask.render_template_string("this is a \n \n {% test %}")
...
File "<unknown>", line 3, in template
TemplateSyntaxError: Encountered unknown tag 'test'.
```

Comment: That seems likely. I guess my real interest is in knowing why -- in the `translate_syntax_error` -- the filename field is null when it is evaluated. Thanks for staying with the thread of my weird question.

Comment: @Bepetersn Updated, I don't think there's much more to it to talk about really.

Comment: A tool I am using (which I contribute to) uses the `render_template` function and is getting this error.

Comment: Wow, actually, I introduced this bug, I'm almost certain now. The only time `render_template` isn't used is a small little patch I made, to add the ability to render a file as jinja templating from within another file. This ultimately falls back on something akin to what you described in your last update, rendering the file contents as a string.

Thanks a lot, I feel stupid.

Comment: @Bepetersn Good, we nailed it down, that's what matters ;)